# Proper setup for tikzit-0.9?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tools

I have installed the following SW on my PC

- basic-miktex-2.9.6361-x64 from https://miktex.org/download
- TXCSetup_2.02Stable_x64 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/texniccenter/files/
- tikzit-0.9 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tikzit/

tikzit-0.9 is a program to make simple drawings. I give a fews screenshots to show where the problem lies.

[image]

After drawing I can copy the generated fragments into a LaTeX-document. 
[image]

After that I can generate the "result" which is clearly NOT what I want.
[image]

I tried to remedy the problem by installing further packages but it did not work out (I have certainly no clue what to do).
[image]

Can you give me some tips how to proceed? Anything that helps is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: The code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer,nodelayer,main}
\tikzstyle{none}=[inner sep=0pt]
\definecolor{hexcolor0xff0000}{rgb}{1.000,0.000,0.000}
\definecolor{hexcolor0x000000}{rgb}{0.000,0.000,0.000}
\definecolor{hexcolor0x00ff00}{rgb}{0.000,1.000,0.000}
\definecolor{hexcolor0x000000}{rgb}{0.000,0.000,0.000}
\definecolor{hexcolor0xffff00}{rgb}{1.000,1.000,0.000}
\definecolor{hexcolor0x000000}{rgb}{0.000,0.000,0.000}
\definecolor{hexcolor0x000000}{rgb}{0.000,0.000,0.000}
\tikzstyle{rn}=[circle,fill=hexcolor0xff0000,draw=hexcolor0x000000,line width=0.8 pt]
\tikzstyle{gn}=[circle,fill=hexcolor0x00ff00,draw=hexcolor0x000000,line width=0.8 pt]
\tikzstyle{yn}=[circle,fill=hexcolor0xffff00,draw=hexcolor0x000000,line width=0.8 pt]
\tikzstyle{simple}=[-,draw=hexcolor0x000000,line width=2.000]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[-,draw=hexcolor0x000000,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},line width=2.000]
\tikzstyle{tick}=[-,draw=hexcolor0x000000,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\draw (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.1);}},line width=2.000]
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=yn] (0) at (-1, 1) {};
        \node [style=rn] (1) at (1, -1) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw [style=simple] (0) to (1);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some log information

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2017.11.28)  19 DEC 2017 01:02
entering extended mode
**./LaTeXpics.tex
(LaTeXpics.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\svgnam.def"
File: svgnam.def 2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box26

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count87
\c@pgf@countb=\count88
\c@pgf@countc=\count89
\c@pgf@countd=\count90
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvips.def

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-dvips.def"
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-postscript.def"
File: pgfsys-common-postscript.def 2008/10/01  (rcs-revision 1.22)
\pgf@objectcount=\count91
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
\pgf@layerbox@edgelayer=\box37
\pgf@layerboxsaved@edgelayer=\box38
\pgf@layerbox@nodelayer=\box39
\pgf@layerboxsaved@nodelayer=\box40
\imagewidth=\skip43
\imagescale=\skip44

(LaTeXpics.aux)
\openout1 = `LaTeXpics.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 28.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros [1

] (LaTeXpics.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10613 strings out of 493313
 220294 string characters out of 3138924
 259200 words of memory out of 3000000
 14015 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,5n,61p,410b,584s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on LaTeXpics.dvi (1 page, 7140 bytes).
```

Comment: Use `pdflatex` instead of `latex` to compile your file. The `pdf` result is correct, but you are looking (with `Yap`) to a `dvi` file which doesn't show the final product.

Comment: @Ignasi: It works just like you predicted! Thank you very much. If you transfer your comment to a short answer I am happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in `Tikzit` but in `TeXniccenter`. It's probably configured to use `LaTeX` as default compiler. In this case the result is a `dvi` file which cannot reproduce the correct figure.

Change TeXniccenter to use `pdflatex` as default compiler and obtained `pdf` files will show the desired figure.

Comment: Again, thank you! You gave me a hint which is invaluable to me because I would have never figured it out by myself.